# Custom fields in rocket chat message

Tags: rocket.chat

I need to add custom fields to rocket chat message. I found in documentation that it can be done for user and for group, but didn't found how to add it to message in group.
I use rocket chat rest API.

Please advice.

Comment: update code, make your own changes or post Feature Request https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/new?template=feature_request.md

Comment: i can do it, but i thought there maybe ready solution. anyway, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is built in functionality for it. Even for groups it's per group type of thing and cannot be applied to all groups with fields at group channel creation.

I just recently made a feature request for that. We can update it and also include custom fields/tags for messages, it would be helpful in my case too.

Github request:
https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/11982

But in the meantime i'm afraid we have to edit the code ourselves and maintain a git repo just for these changes.